# Magento 2 Product Insertion area custom multiselect field how to save?

Tags: magento2, product, custom

I am add a Multiselect into the custom section product insertion area.Please show below screenshot:

[image]

I add this multiselect into the

> F:\xampp-7.2.14\htdocs\magento230\app\Code\Vendor\module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="cs_product_custom_option">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">cs Product Custom Option</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string"/>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="cs_custom_option">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">cs\Customproduct\Model\Source\CustomoptionValues</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Select the options</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
    </field>

    </fieldset>
```

How to save its value into the database with products ?

Thanks in a Advance

Comment: Add a product attribute to achieve this, that's more efficient way and simple enough too. If you need any information, please let me know.

Comment: Hello @G Prathap it's all value is dynamic and come into the database. so attribute is not working

Comment: Any another solution ?

Comment: Did you create this attribute in Setup?

Comment: Yes please update the question with more information exactly what you require.

Comment: Hello @SerhiiHavrylchuk when in a database i add/update data then it is automacilly handled into the custom attribute ?

Comment: Hello @GPrathap I want to save custom field into the product table

Comment: Yes What is the purpose of having custom field instead of an attribute.

Comment: Hii @GPrathap it is for the save custom values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create

> cs\Customproduct\Setup\InstallData.php

```
  <?php
    namespace cs\Customproduct\Setup;

    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

    class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
    {
        private $eavSetupFactory;

        public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
        {
            $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        }

        public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'cs_custom_option',
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Select the options',
                    'input' => 'multiselect',
                    'class' => '',                  
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'cs\Customproduct\Model\Source\CustomoptionValues',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => ''
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i delete the record into the database then into attribute also delete this value ?

Comment: which record do you want to delete?

Comment: In a database id 1 with "abc"

I create the attribute with using your code then i delete the id 1 record then attribute have a "abc" value . i also want to delete this

Comment: Yes it will be deleted

Comment: ohk i will try it

Comment: Hello @Serhii Havrylchuk it is worked great